# Make headers appear like they are in a different folder

Tags: c++, include, clion, include-path

So I have a fancy-organized project that references headers from other projects like this:

```
#include <GeographicLib/Geocentric.hpp>
```

The thing is:

- there is no `GeographicLib` folder
- the project *does* compile with `make`
- when I try to import it in CLion, it doesn't compile as it complains about missing headers

Is there a way to include a folder with `CMakeLists.txt` (the standard used by CLion) to make that `.hpp` file reference-able like it is in that `GeographicLib` folder without having to move files around or change the actual code?

*Edit :* (`.hpp` file is in a folder like `../other_proj/src/geolib`)

Comment: Do you know how the current Makefile does it?

Comment: In `Makefile` you can do something like `INC_PATH = -I/path/f1 -I/path2/f2` and then in the compilation: `g++ $(INC_PATH) ...`

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be as follows: create a dummy target library (`grouped_includes` below) and link it to all your other targets (using `target_link_libraries(target grouped_includes)`)

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink
            "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/other_proj/src/geolib"
            "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GeographicLib") 
add_library(grouped_includes INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(grouped_includes INTERFACE
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}>)
```

Comment: Didn't work, still can't find it. I also tried
execute_process(
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink
        "../other_proj/src/geolib"
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/GeographicLib")
and
execute_process(
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink
        "../other_proj/src/geolib"
        "/GeographicLib")